# getInitialProps cant be accessed

Tags: javascript, function, next.js, react-props, react-functional-component

I am having trouble accessing 'initialReduxState' when setting the hook with 'setReduxStore' in getinitialProps and cant seem to figure out why. Below is a snippet of the code.

```js
export default (App) => {
  return function Redux() {
    let [reduxStore, setReduxStore] = useState();
    let [persistor, setPersistor] = useState();

    Redux.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
      const reduxStore = getOrCreateStore();
      // Provide the store to getInitialProps of pages
      appContext.ctx.reduxStore = reduxStore;

      let appProps = {};
      if (App.getInitialProps) {
        appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
      }

      return {
        ...appProps,
        initialReduxState: reduxStore.getState(),
      };
    };
    setReduxStore(getOrCreateStore(initialReduxState));
    setPersistor(persistStore(reduxStore));

    return <App {...props} reduxStore={reduxStore} persistor={persistor} />;
  };
};
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why I am getting the following error, 'initialReduxState is not defined'? Thanks!

Comment: IMO It would be much easier using `next-redux-wrapper ` + `@reduxjs/toolkit` with nextjs.

Comment: Well, you're not declaring `initialReduxState` anywhere in your code. Did you forget to declare it? For example: `const initialReduxState = reduxStore.getState();`.